# WebAssembly LinkError: _sprintf function import requires a callable

Tags: emscripten, webassembly, emcc

Creating the *WebAssembly.Instance* in JS from a Emscripten compiled WASM which included a call to *sprintf*, results in this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) LinkError: WebAssembly.Instance(): Import #1 module="env" function="*_sprintf*" error: function import requires a callable...

Is *sprintf* not [included by Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#using-libraries) as part of libc?

**The code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    int main() {
        char buffer [50];
        int n, a=5, b=3;
        n=sprintf (buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", a, b, a+b);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

**The compilation command:**

```
emcc src/test.cpp -O3 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o out/test.wasm
```

The *emcc* compilation runs without error.

Commenting out the *sprintf* line runs without error returning 0 as expected.

**What's the reason for this error and how can it be avoided when using sprintf?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is sprintf not included by Emscripten as part of libc?

You're compiling with `SIDE_MODULE=1` which by definition does not link in system libraries.

You can provide your own implementation of `sprintf` or stop compiling as a side module and allow emscripten to take care of it for you.